# Add parts of CSV to another CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, multiple-columns, rows

I have two `.csv` that I need to combine them.

There are two existing CSVs, records.csv (`f1`) and pinsYear.csv (`f2`). `f2.csv` has many more lines of data. `f1` is particular bits of `f2.csv`, with a bunch of extra data. A sample row from each file is as follows:

```
f1.csv - row 1: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h  
f2.csv - row 1: g, i, j
```

Where `g` is the common datum between the two files. Keep in mind, `f2` is basically PINumbers going from 1-50,000, and `f1` is almost random numbers in between, 3, 27, 29, 49, etc.

I want to combine the two files in a new csv, f3.csv, which should have the rows, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, but not adding ALL of the data from `f2.csv`. Examples:
f1.

Starting Code:

```
import csv

f1 = file("records.csv", 'r')
f2 = file("pinsYears.csv", 'r')
f3 = file("allRecords.csv", 'r')

c1 = csvreader(f1)
c2 = csvreader(f2)
c3 = csvreader(f3)

#for records in f1:
#    new_csv_writer.writerow([record[0], int(record[1]) * int(record[4])])

from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open(c1) as f:
reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
    for row in reader:
    for (g, i) in row.items(): 
        columns[g].append(i)
        #idk what to do next
```

Comment: Have a look into the `pandas.read_csv()` and `pandas.DataFrame.merge()` functions.  Here is a link to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.